# How to find a remainder

Tags: c++

I went about this trying by using the modulo (`%`) operator. But each time I see a message that my application has stopped working. Here's my code:

```
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int A;
    int B;
    int C;

    C = A % B;

    cout << "What is A";
    cin >> A;
    cout << "What is B";
    cin >> B;

    cout << A % B;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: obviously, the exact message would be relevant. Also, your code could use a little better indenting.

Comment: Remove your `C=A&B;` statement. That's using uninitialised data.

Comment: Why do you even compute `C` when you don't use it at all?

Answer (score 2):

```
int A;
int B;
int C;
C=A%B;
```

So, you calculate C based on values you did not even set yet,`A` and `B`. They can be anything, and hence, what they actually are is undefined, and so is what happens when you calculate `A%B`. Probably `B` happens to be 0, and that yields an arithmetic error in your CPU.

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined behaviour to read a variable that has not been initialized, such as your `A`, `B` and `C`.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `B` isn't initialized with a value, but the compiler seems to be so kind to set it to 0, so `A%B` does (internally) a division by zero which isn't a valid math operation, so a critical error occurs.

Comment: It's nothing like 'critical error'. It's an undefined behaviour and, in case if `B` is really set to 0 (which cannot be expected, *because we have **UB** here*) a CPU interrupt exception, after which app is stopped and control is returned to the OS. That's why we see *"application has stopped working"* - it has indeed.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek: Seems pretty "critical" to me...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, maybe I was grumbling *a little*, but my point was semantics. You can use word *error* to name dozens of different situations and events, but I think it's good to know what UB is and how to avoid it. That's the kind of knowledge all these crappy web tutorials should teach. But let's leave that alone. *[Sigh]* I'm getting old...

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek: Indeed it is not an error in C++. But from the OS's point of view it most certainly turned out to be! And ... ehm ... you are definitely not old! Only graduated high school in 2012?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, well, I don't know where that feeling comes from. Yet still... *tempus fugit*.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to C++! :)

Make use of C since you are computing it:

```
cout << C << endl; //outputs the computation of A % B
```

In conclusion, here is an edited version of you snippet.

```
#include <iostream> //used for cout and cin
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
   int A; //A,B,C are initialized with no values
   int B;
   int C;

   cout << "What is A";
   cin >> A; //A is given a value

   cout << "What is B";
   cin >> B; //B is given a value

   C = A % B; //previous place in the code is computing empty values. but placing this line of code AFTER values have been set, allows the program to compute.

   cout << C;

   return 0;
}
```